# Marking up ordered definition list

Tags: html

I'm looking for the most semantically correct and sane method of marking up an ordered definition list. I have thought about hte following ways of doing it.

First I used an ordered list with 2 paragraphs within each list item. But then I remembered the definition list element.

```
<dl>
  <dt>Something</dt>
  <dd>Definition</dd>

  <dt>Something2</dt>
  <dd>Definition2</dd>
</dl>
```

However as I need to be able to access each definition programmatically through Javascript I'm not sure that this would work.

The solution to this might be to separate the definitions into different `dl` tags. But that doesn't look very good at all. Is there a more correct way? Or am I incorrect in assuming that is more complicated to access the "normal" definition list through Javascript?

```
<dl>
  <dt>Something</dt>
  <dd>Definition</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
  <dt>Something2</dt>
  <dd>Definition2</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? what's the problem with the first example?

Comment: Write shorter precised questions.
It helps very much.

Comment: Some interesting historical context to this question: the XHTML2 spec had a `<di>` element that would be used as a grouping of related `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements. There has been discussion on www-style about adding a `::di` pseudo-element to CSS3 that would serve the same purpose for styling. An interesting read: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2009Dec/0264.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *However as I need to be able to access each definition programmatically through Javascript I'm not sure that this would work.*

Just get each definition term `<dt>` and then get the element next to it in the DOM tree, which should always be the definition description `<dd>`. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) is of great help in here. Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2172138</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#dl dt').each(function(i, dt) {
                    dt = $(dt);
                    dds = dt.nextAll().map(function() { return $(this).is('dd') ? this : false; });
                    alert(dt.text() + " = " + dds.text());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <dl id="dl">
            <dt>Term1</dt><dd>Desc1a</dd><dd>Desc1b</dd>
            <dt>Term2</dt><dd>Desc2a</dd>
            <dt>Term3</dt><dd>Desc3a</dd><dd>Desc3b</dd>
        </dl>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the perfectly valid use case of having multiple definitions per term.

Answer (score -3):

Use names and IDs.

```
<dl id="1">
```

Document.getElementById("1");

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById

Comment: A nitpick: IDs cannot start with a number.