# Marking up ordered description list

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I knew there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172138/marking-up-ordered-definition-list) but my situation is a little more complicated.

I am working on representing a type of [Linguistics Olympiad](http://ioling.org) problems, which give solvers several sentences written in an unknown language and their corresponding translations, like this:

```
1. edèì âno nwạ́sesè ozyí lẹlemù à? edèì ânò wei ga òkí nwạsese ozyí lẹlemù.
Will this man frighten the deceived thief?
This man said that he (this man) would not frighten the deceived thief.

2. ạvùràmù kịnono amemùrè ânò à? ạvùràmù wei ga òkì kịnono amemùrè ânò.
Did the woman resemble this girl?
The woman said that she (the woman) did resemble this girl.

... another five sentences

from IOL 2014, Problem 4
```

Solvers need to deduce grammars of this language and finish a couple of assignments. Two types of assignments appear all the time: translate from and to the unknown language.

Originally, I decided to use ordered list. But I soon realized those sentences actually consist a name-value group. But:

1. The number before each sentence is meaningful for referencing purpose.
2. The counter is reused in assignment sections. I either need to use a counter in css or explicitly set `start` attribute on an ordered list if I choose to use it.
3. In translation assignments, only one version of sentences is given, in either the unknown language or the Solver-ese. So those sentences don't consist a name-value group.

Here is my question:

Should I use description list for those sentences. In the given data set only? Or in both the data set and sentences in translation assignments?

And if so, how should I represent the following content:

```
Translate into Engenni:
11. Will the old man resemble this coughing youth?
The child said that he (the old man) would not resemble this coughing youth.

12. Did this beaten woman not frighten the man?
This beaten woman said that she (this beaten woman) did not frighten the man.
```

in a description list? According to the standard, I should not use `<dd>` but in the data set, English sentences are in `<dd>`.

---

A somehow irrelevant question: if I use ordered list, should I use two `<p>` for two versions of the same translation? Or should I use `<i>` to explicitly mark the version in the unknown language? Or maybe `<i>` is inappropriate so I need to use a semantically-neutral `<span>`?

Comment: Is your list really ordered? If you'd used names instead of numbers as references, and placed the list items in a different order, would that change the problem? If not, then you don't have an ordered list.

Comment: @Alohci The sentences' order do have no special meaning but since I am simply reproducing problems, I should keep consistence between my web version with the already published contest problems. From this perspective, my list is ordered.

Comment: Well personally, if the paragraphs were not semantically ordered, just incidentally ordered, I wouldn't use an ordered list, since just using a dl would retain that incidental ordering. But it's quite subjective.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not use an ordered list (`ol`) here. This element is only to be used when the ordering of the items is meaningful, not just because they are sorted somehow (by an "arbitrary" counter, for example).

And if the counter is important content, you should have it as plain text content, not via `ol`’s default styling. Problems with relying on the default `ol` counter:

- Users cannot <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for a number.
- When users copy-paste the content, the counter might not be included.
- Users with user-agents that don’t support the `start` attribute would get a wrong counter.
- CSS! Don’t rely on it for conveying *content*.

---

For the data-set, you could use a `dl`:

```
<section>
  <h1>Translations</h1>

  <dl>

    <dt>
      <b id="translation-1">1</b>
      <p lang="und">edèì âno nwạ́sesè ozyí lẹlemù à? edèì ânò wei ga òkí nwạsese ozyí lẹlemù.</p>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <p lang="en">Will this man frighten the deceived thief? This man said that he (this man) would not frighten the deceived thief.</p>
    </dd>

    <dt>
      <b id="translation-2">2</b>
      <p lang="und">ạvùràmù kịnono amemùrè ânò à? ạvùràmù wei ga òkì kịnono amemùrè ânò.</p>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <p lang="en">Did the woman resemble this girl? The woman said that she (the woman) did resemble this girl.</p>
    </dd>

  </dl>

</section>
```

An alternative to `dl` could be to simply use HTML5’s sectioning elements and headings:

```
<section>
  <h1>Translations</h1>

  <article>
    <h1 id="translation-1">1</h1>
    <p lang="und">edèì âno nwạ́sesè ozyí lẹlemù à? edèì ânò wei ga òkí nwạsese ozyí lẹlemù.</p>
    <p lang="en">Will this man frighten the deceived thief? This man said that he (this man) would not frighten the deceived thief.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h1 id="translation-2">2</h1>
    <p lang="und">ạvùràmù kịnono amemùrè ânò à? ạvùràmù wei ga òkì kịnono amemùrè ânò.</p>
    <p lang="en">Did the woman resemble this girl? The woman said that she (the woman) did resemble this girl.</p>
  </article>

</section>
```

Using `table` [would be possible, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579446/1591669), but I’d not prefer it in this case. It would probably also be harder to achieve the desired styling then.

---

The choice for the translation assignments should not depend on the markup you use for the data-set. But when you explicitly provide the counter, this would be placed in `dt`, so the English sentences end up in `dd` anyway. But instead of `dl`, you could also use `ul`, or, again, sectioning elements with headings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, does each sentence fulfill the definition of ``<article>``? "The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication." from W3.org.

Comment: @MinshengLiu: If I understood your case correctly, I’d say yes, `article` is appropriate for the sentence in an unknown language and its translation, together they form an "independent item of content". However, if you think `article` is not appropriate, go with `section` -- this doesn’t change anything outline-wise (you’d have implicit sections anyway as soon as you use headings).